# How can I determine the windows libraries required for a specific win32 api call?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, py2exe

I'm using several windows api modules like `win32wnet`, `win32file`, `win32con`, and others but only a few methods from these.

I'm packaging my app with py2exe (bundle_files==3) and it is hit-and-miss if they run on other windows platforms.

I'd like to:
1) package all the required and only the appropriate libraries.  I don't want to rely on what is already supposed to be installed on the OS if at all possible.

Or:
2) I would like to write manifests to connect my app to the approprate versions of existing dlls. (if packaging the dll is not legal)

errors provided by python at runtime are vague:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

the docs (ex: `help(win32wnet)`) don't seem to be of much use.

How can I identify which native windows libraries are required by my app?

Comment: What function are you tring to call that isnt in the DLL?

Comment: @ Toby Allen  `win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2` is one.  I have a long list of others.  I want(ed) a general solution for finding libs that are used by these funcs (a solution which I have found already -- see my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might find that shipping core windows dlls as part of your app is not allowed by Microsoft.

You should write your software to work with whats available on the machine unless its something like comctrls32 which has several versions.

Comment: Good point.  but it does not answer the question.  Looking for a method for determining the dependencies path of .pyd's

Comment: It addresses the problem, but does not solve it.  Me: "Doc, it hurts when I do this."  Doc: "Don't do that."

Comment: @Toby Allen   I know the libs are available on the machine.  But i get an ImportError because apparently pywin32 cannot find them or is finding a SxS version that was not intended to be used by  that version pywin32.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the .pyd (win32wnet in this case) to discover if any .dll dependencies are broken.  Then either 1) include a manifest in the package (if you know where the native libraries are) or 2) bundle the .dll in the package (if allowed by MS)

Comment: You cannot bundle the DLL even if MS allowed it. It doesn't work. You can't put the vista user32, say, on xp. It doesn't work. You don't need any manifests to load the basic win32 dlls. Your actual problem is not what you think it is.

Comment: @David Heffernan  Then why does py2exe bundle .dlls with a package?

Comment: I think it bundles Python DLLs. Like python27.dll and any DLLs needed for the C runtime, perhaps. Also any required PYDs and so on. It really should not bundle Windows DLLs. That cannot work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but it does.  For example in this case, py2exe automatically bundled mpr.dll with the package.  My prob was that mpr was also dependent on c++ runtime and coudn't find it. (due to SxS?)  Once I wrote a manifest for mpr.dll, everything seems to work again.

Comment: py2exe should not be doing that. But I've no idea why it is. mpr.dll does not have a dependency on the C runtime. It's a system component and they don't depend on the MSVC runtime.